# Code aware / exact entry version of keyboard for Android?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I hate it when I am writing code* and all the English rules get applied. When I type i++, it shows I++. I have to actually like press the lowercase i accept option before I type the ++

or not respecting my camel case (splitting words automatically).

Let variable = ...

I don't want the let being capitalised as its not the first word in a sentence. It's code, not English.

*Note: I'm not saying I write code on my phone ,lol, this is like notes for Evernote, or in a reddit response, not real code that is actually going to run somewhere

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.